# Validate a date comprised of 3 fields in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, date, plsql

I am not an expert in PLSQL. Normally to validate a date I would do something like this:

```
dt_variable := TO_DATE(<INPUT_DATE>,<DATE_FORMAT>)
```

and if it returned an error I would know the date is invalid. I have a different requirement now though. The day, month, and year are all separate text fields. I need to make sure the day is valid from 1-31, month is JAN-DEC (3 letter texts) and year is in the format YYYY. I also need to check if the date is valid, for instance no June 31st. Since I have 3 fields ow I can't use the to_date function is there any other function i can use to accomplish this. I have searched, but could not find anything and am hoping a sql expert might now of a method.

Comment: Just use || to concatenate the three elements...  but that doesn't answer your validation question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to validate the separate elements at all; concatenate them together with the appropriate separator, and treat the combined value as one; e.g.:

```
to_date(l_day || '/' || l_month || '/' || l_year, 'DD/MON/YYYY')
```

Using month names or abbreviations can be a problem as you're relying on the NLS settings matching. If you know the values will always be English you can specify the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE with the optional third argument to `to_date`. It's often safer to use month numbers; and an unambiguous date format like YYYY-MM-DD. It doesn't sound like you have control over that though.

Comment: If your months are formatted as JAN, FEB and so forth you can us dd/mon/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy, but you can also just validate that sort of info.